# Would it be possible for dark 'energy' to follow the laws of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, dark-energy

Would it be possible for dark 'energy' to follow the laws of thermodynamics? I hope, this is something that can be answered.

Comment: why would you think not?

Answer (score 1):

To follow the laws of thermodynamics, we need 3 things:

1. It should be many point-like particles.
2. There should be a quasi-random energy exchange between its particles.
3. We need enough time to get a thermodynamical equilibrium (-> the system should exist at least many times longer as the characteristic time of the energy exchange).

Now the problem is that nearly nothing is known from the dark energy. It is not known if it is from particles or it is only some QM or GR phenomenon. Thus, it is not known if it follows the laws of the thermodynamics.

Comment: My naive layman intuition says, yes it is from antigravitating particles, but I can't prove it.